# Unable to use reactive forms in Ionic Angular 7 project due to missing app.module.ts file

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic Angular 7 project and I'm trying to use reactive forms in my application. As *app.module.ts* is removed from Ionic Angular 7, I tried to check through few articles found on Internet. However, when I try to import the ReactiveFormsModule in my *main.ts* file as mentioned in those articles, it didn't work.

Sample of code from *main.ts* after importing ReactiveFormsModule:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    importProvidersFrom(IonicModule.forRoot({}),ReactiveFormsModule),
    provideRouter(routes),
  ],
});
```

I'm not sure how to proceed with using reactive forms in my Ionic Angular 7 project. How can I add the ReactiveFormsModule to my project and use reactive forms?

Comment: Please post the code of where you are trying to use it. I would presume since it is a stand alone component you need to add it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import it in the component it's being used in:

```
@Component({
  standalone:true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule]
})
```